# Object literal error in colon

Tags: json

I am getting an error in object literals when I run my file index.html it says Unexpected token : but when checked it in JSONLINT the json is valid. May I know why is there an error. Thank you.

```
{
  "routers": [{
    "Id": 13,
    "Locale": "en-au, en-nz",
    "Model": "NBG-418N_v2",
    "Brand": "ZyXEL",
    "ModelType": "n/a",
    "Tested": "True",
    "Compatible": "True",
    "Created": "\/Date(1479803884500)\/",
    "CreatedBy": "Evan Sevilla (TS-PH)",
    "Modified": "\/Date(1481028732650)\/",
    "ModifiedBy": "Evan Sevilla (TS-PH)",
    "Solution": "\u003cdiv\u003eAdditionally, please perform the steps on this Knowledge Base Article:\u003cbr /\u003e\u003cbr /\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdl class=\"topFAQ\"\u003e\u003cdt\u003e\u003ca href=\"https://esupport.trendmicro.com/en-us/home/pages/technical-support/home-network-security/1115759.aspx?vwd=RouterCompatibility-_-prd=DM00-_-src=ZyXELNBG418Nv2-_-loc=Default\"\u003eEnabling the compatibility mode of your Home Network Security \u003c/a\u003e\u003c/dt\u003e\u003cdd\u003eKnow how to manually turn on the compatibility mode of Home Network Security.\u003c/dd\u003e\u003c/dl\u003e",
    "ComMode": "True",
    "EntityState": 2,
    "EntityKey": {
        "EntitySetName": "KB_DiamondRouter",
        "EntityContainerName": "SPTEntities",
        "EntityKeyValues": [{
            "Key": "Id",
            "Value": 13
        }],
        "IsTemporary": false
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: is it _definitely_ this object which is the problem? It might be useful to show us the code in context, and the exact error. If it's definitely this, you could just try removing each property until you find the one(s) it doesn't like, then it narrows down the problem a bit.

Comment: I've just put that script in my index.html file under the script element. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: what, literally just that? To what purpose? Unless you assign it to a variable it doesn't do anything and it's not a valid JS statement on its own, which might explain the error. e.g. you'd have to do `var myData = { "routers": [{` ...etc. It's not clear what you've done - I repeat please show it in context, inside the script block.

Comment: Thank you. It works. I've just copied the json file in the return data of my ajax requests. I forgot to add a var. Im getting rusty now. Thank you very much.